# Clicking an element doesn't trigger same behaviour as manually clicking it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've found the element I want to click but whenever Selenium clicks it the page doesn't exhibit the same behaviour as when I manually click it myself. If you go to https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-mcdonalds-victorialondon/menu, select "Double Big Mac Meal" and click on an item in the popup you'll notice that the popup automatically scrolls you to the next section and when all required sections are selected the button at the bottom lights up orange. However, when I run the below script it clicks the element fine but it doesn't trigger the auto-scroll nor does the button light up orange once all required elements are clicked.

Essentially clicking the element with selenium is different from clicking it manually but I have no idea why. I've tried:

- Webdrive Wait
- ActionChains
- execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();"
- Clicking the parent (and all parents) of the element
- Clicking the child of the element
- Pressing "Enter" on the element instead of clicking

Does anyone know why clicking the element isn't resulting in the same behaviour or what else I can try to click the element?

Here's a minimum runnable example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json
import ssl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import difflib

url = "https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-mcdonalds-victorialondon/menu"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
main = "Double Big Mac Meal"
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button_o-btn_1KX8u:nth-child(2)").click()
h3_tags = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
for tag in h3_tags:
    if tag.text == main:
        tag.click()

add_ons = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "c-itemSelector-section-label")))
for a in add_ons:
    add_on = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')
add_on_list = []
for i in add_on:
    add_on_list.append(i.text)
action = ActionChains(browser)
element1 = "Side Salad"
if element1:
    spans = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
    for span in spans:
        if span.text == element1:
            popup = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.c-megaModal-document--scrollable')
                   
            x = False
            while x == False:
                try:
                    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[contains(text(), "{element1}")]')
                    time.sleep(2)

                    x = True
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    popup.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution which light on the order button

```
main = "Double Big Mac Meal"
h3_tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[contains(.,"Double Bacon Egg McMuffin® Meal") and contains(.,"Double Bacon Egg McMuffin® Meal")]')
h3_tags = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
for tag in h3_tags:
    if tag.text == main:
        print(tag.text)
        tag.click()



addons_selected = ['Medium Meal','Side Salad', 'McCafé® Flat White' ]

#select only option, not things to remove, for that its just another class to add
add_ons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH , '//span[@data-test-id="single-select-name"]')))

add_on_list = []
time.sleep(1)

id = -1
for i in add_ons:
    id += 1
    if( i.text in addons_selected):
        print(i.text)
        but = i.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::label')
        try:
            but.click()
            time.sleep(2)
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', add_ons[id - 3])
            time.sleep(2)
            but.click()
            time.sleep(2)
        add_on_list.append(i.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but hat doesn't seem to have fixed it, I'm getting an error on the except statement when looping through the add_ons. It realises it can't see the "Medium Meal" button so goes into the except part but for some reason doesn't scroll it into view and instead scrolls way past it, then when it tries to click the button again it still isn't in view and it crashes

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your xpath of the button since you mentioned about an error message saying that the button cannot be seen and also it will scroll past it.

Also, try to use an explicit wait until the element is visible before clicking the button.

```
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id')))
```